# Chrome won't find Gmail on Lion 10.7.3; Safari won't launch at all

Tags: macos, google-chrome, gmail, safari

Recently did a clean install of 10.7.3.  Use Chrome, Firefox, and occasionally Safari.  Things are fairly OK on all applications (previous upgrade without clean reinstall ended me up with all kinds of bizarre freezes when working in Office 2011 that my tech group installed as a matter of course along with the upgrade).  Now, after a couple weeks, chrome can no longer find gmail, and Safari won't open at all.  Firefox still works.

Comment: What do you mean by chrome can no longer find gmail? Please paste the error message.

Comment: Here's the error message.  Basically Chrome window just sits there with the time circle icon slowly turning counterclockwise]:"Google Chrome could not load the webpage because mail.google.com took too long to respond. The website may be down, or you may be experiencing issues with your Internet connection.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Check your Internet connection. Restart any router, modem, or other network devices you may be using." ...   There is more 'advice' about checking proxy servers.  I looked but nothing informative.